# Trouble accessing some methods of a dynamic object

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm writing a utility that allows end users to perform some Selenium tests against my company's web app, so far so good. Here's the issue: I want to allow users to choose the type of selenum.webdriver object they are going to implement, based on whether they have chrome or firefox installed on their system.

so, I initialize a list of objects to let us know what the user has selected

```
public List<object> BuildBrowserAccess(string browserEngine)

    {

        OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver driverC = null;
        OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver driverF = null;
        if (browserEngine == "Firefox")
        {
            driverF = new OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else if (browserEngine == "Chrome\t")
        {
            driverC = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();
        }

        List<object> browserEngines = new List<object>();
        browserEngines.Add(driverC);
        browserEngines.Add(driverF);

        return browserEngines; 
    }
```

Then back in the main routine, assign whichever is selected (i.e. not null) to a dynamic object then convert the object to static using "as":

```
List<object> browserEngines = mainActions.BuildBrowserAccess(browserEngine);

            if (browserEngines[0] != null )
            {
                 driver = browserEngines[0];
                 finDriver = driver as OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver;

            }
             else
            {
                driver = browserEngines[1];
                finDriver = driver as OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver;
            }
```

Even at runtime, the conversion looks successful, and I'm able to use some methods of the FirefoxDriver namespace, but many other methods that work just fine with a statically typed object throw a RuntimeBinderException... I'm just about stumped, and any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create only one `driver` variable of type `IWebDriver` of it doesn't have to be specifically initialized, use `var`?

And in case you need to check the specific type of `driver` you could do

```
if(driver.GetType() == typeof(FirefoxDriver))
{
    //do your Firefox stuff
}
else
{
    //do another browser stuff
}
```